# GET 404 Not Found when loading stylesheet

Tags: go, static, web-deployment, static-files, go-fiber

I am having problems with Go Fiber's Static file server.
I want to load a css stylesheet which is used within a template. The template itself works fine.

```
func main() {
    // Create a new engine.
    engine := html.New("./views", ".html")

    // Fiber instance
    app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{Views: engine})

    app.Static("/static", "./views")

    app.Get("/layout", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        // Render index within layouts/main
        return c.Render("index", fiber.Map{
            "Title": "Hello, World!",
        }, "layouts/main")
    })

    // Start server
    log.Print(app.Listen(":3000"))

}
```

Where my file structure is: (where a -> denotes it is a directory)

```
-> views
    -> layouts
        main.css
        main.html
    index.html
main.go
```

And the contents of main.html are:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/layouts/main.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
{{embed}}
</body>
</html>
```

The file ./views definitely exists, as when I add this to main, nothing is printed to log:

```
if _, err := os.Stat("./views"); os.IsNotExist(err) {
    log.Print("Path doesn't exist")
}
```

When I run it on localhost and use inspect element to see the network, http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/layouts/main.css is correctly queried but a 404 error is thrown. If I go to http://127.0.0.1:3000/static I get a message saying `Cannot GET /static`. I think it may be a file path issue but I have tried many different combinations of .s, /s, etc and got nowhere.

How can I solve this 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.
When I moved stylesheets into their own folder, the css worked just fine.

Thus my file structure now is this:

```
-> styles
    main.css
-> views
    -> layouts
        main.html
    index.html
main.go
```

And in `func main()`, the Static server now is `app.Static("/static", "./styles")`. Nothing else was changed.